# How to make \tfrac work in >{}?

Tags: tables, math-mode

When I used `>{$\sqrt\bgroup\tfrac}c<{\egroup$}`, I got the following output. 
The weird part happened at the last column. How to fix it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
{
    >{$}c<{^\circ$}
    >{$\tfrac1 2\sqrt\bgroup}c<{\egroup$}
    >{$\tfrac1 2\sqrt\bgroup}c<{\egroup$}
    >{$\sqrt\bgroup\tfrac}c<{\egroup$}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\theta$}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sin\theta$}&
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\cos\theta$}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\tan\theta$}\\
\midrule
0&
    0&
        4&
            0 4\\
30&
    1&
        3&
            1 3\\
45&
    2&
        2&
            2 2\\
60&
    3&
        1&
            3 1\\
90&
    4&
        0&
            4 0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Bonus: Please make the rows a bit taller. And if it is possible, can we extract the second and third column to be used for the fourth column?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not use `\bgroup` to enclose macro arguments.

As noted in comments `\sqrt` doesn't as it happen take its argument as a macro argument.

The last column is different because `&` is a TeX primitive which causes the text from `<{...}` to be inserted as soon as it is seen, however `\\` is a macro and macros are not expanded while scanning for arguments. So you would need to use a dummy last column that is always empty so your scan always ends with `&` or (with some loss of functionality) use `\cr` primitive rather than `\\`. Or (best) insert `\\` rather than `\endgroup` into the preamble with `<{\\}` and in the `>{...}` don't use `\sqrt` directly but use a macro using delimited arguments `\foo#1\\` this delimited argument will then always pick up the content (and you have to put a real \ back if you are in the last row)

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\def\getNum#1\relax{\gdef\num{#1}$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$}

\def\getDenum#1\\{\gdef\denum{#1}$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$&$\sqrt{\tfrac{\num}{\denum}}$\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
{
    >{$}c<{^\circ$}
    >{\getNum}c
    >{\getDenum}c
    c
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\theta$}&
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sin\theta$}&
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\cos\theta$}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\tan\theta$}\\
\midrule
0&
    0&
        4\\
30&
    1&
        3\\
45&
    2&
        2\\
60&
    3&
        1\\
90&
    4&
        0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's not true what you're writing. The `\sqrt` is defined as a `\radical`, and a `\radical` takes a `<math field>` as "argument". A `<math field>` can be `{<math mode material>}`, where `{}` are explicitly allowed to be `\bgroup` and `\egroup`. For details see the TeXbook, page 291.

Comment: By the way, the OP's code has the effect that the `\tfrac` in the last column takes `\ignorespaces` as its first argument. Unfortunately I can't tell _why_ this is happening.

Comment: @HendrikVogt yes although `\DeclareRobustCommand\sqrt{\@ifnextchar[\@sqrt\sqrtsign}` use of `bgroup` in that way isn't supported in latex even if it accidentally works (but I'll edit the text a bit)

Comment: Well, LaTeX uses TeX and nothing else. `\sqrtsign` is defined as `\radical "270370\relax` (almost the same as TeX's `\sqrt`), so what I wrote about `\radical` still applies. (But yes, you're right, what I wrote above was an oversimplification.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt yes I was agreeing with your comment:-)

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out `:-)` (I didn't notice in the hurry ...)

Answer (score 10):

The `collcell` package by Martin Scharrer solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand\getnumerator[1]{$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$\gdef\numerator{#1}}
\newcommand\getdenominator[1]{$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{#1}$\gdef\denominator{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
  {
   >{$}c<{^\circ$}
   >{\collectcell\getnumerator}c<{\endcollectcell}
   >{\collectcell\getdenominator}c<{\endcollectcell}
   >{$\sqrt{\tfrac{\numerator}{\denominator}}$}c
  }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\theta$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\sin\theta$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\cos\theta$}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\tan\theta$}\\
\midrule
0  & 0 & 4 & \\\addlinespace
30 & 1 & 3 & \\\addlinespace
45 & 2 & 2 & \\\addlinespace
60 & 3 & 1 & \\\addlinespace
90 & 4 & 0 & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]